# Redirect to another site while 404

Tags: nginx, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have site with ssl https://example.com

And sub-domain without ssl http://site.example.com

Needs to redirect to site http://site.example.com when 404 error happens

My nginx conf file look like there

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.com.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    error_page 404 = 301 http://site.example.com/;
  }
}
```

Error 404 occurs but no redirection

Comment: Try adding: `proxy_intercept_errors on;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the 404 response is the upstream `localhost:5050`.

Normally, `nginx` will just pass these through. If you want to process upstream responses with the `error_page` directive, you will need to set `proxy_intercept_errors` to `on`.

For example:

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) for details.